Automation: Cypress+TypeScript -Getting error upon runing the test (may be domain related issue)
I am getting error after 'clickOnLoginButton,
My original domain is getting changed after I clicked on the login button. That may be the reason for the error. How can I resolve the error?
Error:-

(uncaught exception)Error: null This error was thrown by a cross origin page. If you wish to suppress this error you will have to use the cy.origin command to handle the error prior to visiting the page. cy.origin('https://inspiration-innovation-sdkm-dev-ed.scratch.lightning.force.com', () => { cy.on('uncaught:exception', (e) => { if (e.message.includes('Things went bad')) { // we expected this error, so let's ignore it // and let the test continue return false } }) }) cy.visit('https://inspiration-innovation-sdkm-dev-ed.scratch.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/SetupOneHome/home')***
Here is my code
///<reference types="Cypress"/>
export class LoginPage{
loginPage_UserName='#username'
LoginPage_Password='#password'
LoginPage_LoginButton='#Login'

navigateLoginPage(){
cy.visit('https://inspiration-innovation-sdkm-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com/')

}

enterUserName(userName: string){
    cy.get(this.loginPage_UserName)
      .type(userName)
}

enterPassword(password: string){
    cy.get(this.LoginPage_Password)
      .type(password)
}

clickOnLoginButton(){
  
    cy.get(this.LoginPage_LoginButton).click()

}
}

I tried adding following just before the click button, but it don't work
cy.origin('https://inspiration-innovation-sdkm-dev-ed.scratch.lightning.force.com', () => { cy.on('uncaught:exception', (e) => { if (e.message.includes('Things went bad')) { // we expected this error, so let's ignore it // and let the test continue return false } }) }) cy.visit('https://inspiration-innovation-sdkm-dev-ed.scratch.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/SetupOneHome/home')

I suspect your error message does not include 'Things went bad'.
